# asyncronous API request in Angula

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

Im refactoring a billing system made with Angular + NodeJs.

I need to make some API calls to my backend, first to get Customers, then Invoices and finally Students. I call the functions in ngOnInit. Then I need to manipulate the Arrays mixing the data.

If I call the functions in order, sometimes the code can't access all the info, for example:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCustomers();
    this.getInvoices();
    this.getStudents();
    this.doSomeCalculations();
```

Sometimes customers[] (defined by this.getCustomers() is still empty when this.doSomeCalculations() starts.

I tried with setTimeout, with no improvement.

Finally what I did to make everything work was calling getInvoices() in the getCustomers() response, and getStudents() in getInvoices() response. So getInvoices() asign the response to invoices[] and then calls the next function, and so on. And doSomeCalculations() only starts when all the data has been asigned to variables.

But this solution is ugly. I know there is a better way of doing this, but I don't know how. Maybe it is related to promises or async-await?

My base code for the API calls is as follows:

```
getCustomers(){
    this._customerService.getCustomers()
      .subscribe(
      { next: (res) => {
        this.customers = res;
        this.getInvoices();
      },
        error: (err) => {
        console.log(<any>err);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

It is the same for getInvoices and getStudents.

How can I improve my code here?

Comment: look into chaining http-calls. `switchMap` sounds like a perfect rxjs operator for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using async/await + promises.

For each method definition, you could return the data as a promise, then use async/await at the top level. I see you're using observables for the data calls, but you don't have to. Promises may be better here.

Example:

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
  try {
    await getCustomers();
    ...
  } ...
```

}

```
getCustomers(): Promise<Customers[]>{
  return new Promise((err, resp) => {
          ...
          resolve(resp)
  })
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To make multiple API calls using RxJS forkJoin operator.

```
fetchData() {
    forkJoin({
      customers: this.getCustomers(),
      invoices: this.getInvoices(),
      students: this.getStudents(),
      calculations: this.doSomeCalculations()
    }).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        return [];
      })
    ).subscribe(result => {
      // Process the data as needed
      console.log("Customers:", result.customers);
      console.log("Invoices:", result.invoices);
      console.log("Students:", result.students);
      console.log("Calculations:", result.calculations);
  
      // Additional processing or logic here
    });
  }
```